documents4j with Java 17
Currently documents4j is built with Java 11, which will be soon end of support (by Oracle the standard support already ends, by SAP it will be end 2024). My questions are:

Has documents4j plan to upgrade from Java 11 to Java 17?
If not, how would be roughly the effort? Can only part of it be upgraded (like documents4j-transformer-msoffice)?
Is there any Java vendor that supports Java 11 with a reasonable cost?

Many thanks!
Tried to build with Java 17 and it is not supported

Those first two questions should probably be put to the developers of documents4j rather than here. Though note that code compiled to target Java 11 should run on Java 17 (unless the code relies, e.g., on accessing the internals of modules, though worst case that should be "fixable" with an appropriate --add-opens and/or --add-exports).

It seems not so bad. After update maven war plugin in pom.xml, it seems ok to be built with Java 17.
Thanks, documents4j, you rock!
